# How to add custom buttons to keyboard and customize action for the return key

Tags: iphone

how can we add coustom buttons in defaultkeypad or how to write action for "go" or "done" button in keypad,,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for writing action fro "go" and "done" button you have to implement the correspondence delegate of your component, for example if you are using a UItextField you have to implement the following delegate -

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField

Answer (score 0):

Hook the `UITextField`'s `Did End On Exit` action.